# combine 2 id's with advanced params

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to consolidate 2 calls into 1 but am not sure how due to the 'extra's that one of the classes has for sub-content.

```
$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").click(function() { //stuff     });
$('#myid').click(function() {   //same stuff    });
```

normally, i'd just do `$('.abc , #myid')` but `myid` HAS `xyz` sub children that I do NOT want to be effected in this case (unlike `.abc`), so i can't combine all the not stuff.

What's the best way to merge these two so i don't re-write the same 'stuff' function?

Comment: We'd need to know what "stuff" is most likely, though `$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").add('#myid')` might work.

Comment: None of the suggestions below seem to work.  Which means, i must have something else going on that is causing the myid action to not take the click.  I appreciate the advice and i'll do some more twekaing and get one of these working in time.   Will accept once i figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a named function

```
function doStuff() { /* stuff */ }

$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").click(doStuff);
$('#myid').click(doStuff);
```

Answer (score 2):

If putting it in one call is crucial, you can simplify the first selector into

```
$('.abc :not(.xyz)')
```

That would allow you to use

```
$('.abc :not(.xyz), #myid')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").add('#myid').click(function() {
  // stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still do something similar to `$('.abc , #myid')` using the .add method.

```
$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").add('#myid').click(function(){ /* stuff*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
function doStuff(){
  // your same stuffs
}

$('.abc').children().not(".xyz").click(doStuff);
$('#myid').click(doStuff);
```